# how to add emojis view in chat app in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

How to add emojis in a chat view in xamarin.forms...just like in message sender or in whats app there is symbol around a text box to view and select emojis.i am using the default emojis shown in keypad but now according to client requirement i need to show symbol separately.

Comment: yes i did that.......

Comment: I guess you didn't notice mine, to go back to your question, you'll need a custom keyboard for each separate os, or could make a keyboard in the page itself so it's crossplatform but that's a lot more work